# Falling images randomly

Tags: javascript, image, animation, canvas

Do you think it's possible to include random images inside the squares?

I would like to keep the gradient color in and on the border though, so, just applied my images randomly inside the shapes.

https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/xZjExY

```
ξ.fillStyle = ξ.strokeStyle = 'hsl(' + ~~(t + .2*y) + ',100%,65%)';
```

I tried to edit that part but no success...

Thanks guys

Comment: You can use images in canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images

Comment: @jmargolisvt Thank you for your answer, I'm trying since yesterday to do it but I can't find how to with this plugin... Could you show me how to on the pen? Thanks a lot